# why does my second dropdown is copying the change action of my first dropdown

Tags: jquery, select, laravel-4, onchange

I have this 2 dropdown which have the same function in onchange where if i Select Make Express Payment it should be able to show a modal of express payment but the problem is that the second dropdown is just copying the action of the first dropdown

```
<div class="sample" data-key="1001">
    <form class="form" id="form-1001">
    <select class="form-control">                                                                                                                                
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>                                                                                                                                            
        <option value="express">Make Express Payment</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="sample" data-key="1002">
    <form class="form" id="form-1002">
    <select class="form-control">                                                                                                                                
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>                                                                                                                                            
        <option value="express">Make Express Payment</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

for example

- 1st drpdwn = 1
- 2nd drpdwn = make express button

the scenario will be the second dropdown will not show the modal but if

- 1st drpdwn = make express button (will show the modal)
- 2nd drpdwn = 1

the result will be the 2nd dropdown will also show the modal supposed to be not show.

here is the jquery code `$(this).data('key')` is 1002 or 1003 .

```
$( ".sample" ).each(function() {
    alert($(this).data('key'));
    $( "#form-"+$(this).data('key')).change(function() {
        if ($("option:selected"). val() === "express") {
            $('#express-payment-modal').modal('show');
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: You neglected to restrict your selection of the selected option inside the handler function to any specific element, so …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a generic jQuery selector in the change function - `$("option:selected")` this will give you two elements in array. when there is val() call, it gives you value of the 1st element in the array. Try this -

```
`$( "#form-"+$(this).data('key')).change(function(e) {
    if (e.target.value === "express") {
     //...
    }
 });
```